# D3 SelectAll except one class to modify opacity

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I'm working on the following radial graph:

```
 //Fade out all players except the first player
        g.selectAll(".teamArc")
                .attr("opacity", 0.6);

        g.selectAll(".teamCircle")
                .attr("opacity", 0.6);

        //Select the first player by default
        var firstPlayer = arcAndCircleG.first();

        firstPlayer.select(".teamArc")
                    .classed("active", true)
                    .attr("id", "selected")
                    .attr("stroke", "green")
                    .attr("stroke-width", "1px")
                    .attr("opacity", 1);

        firstPlayer.select(".teamCircle")
                    .classed("active", true)
                    .attr("id", "selected")
                    .attr("stroke", "green")
                    .attr("stroke-width", "1px")
                    .attr("opacity", 1);


        teamCircles.on("mouseover", function(d,i){

            g.selectAll(".teamArc").transition()
                    .duration(200)
                    .attr("opacity", function(d,j){
                        return j != i ? 0.6 : 1;
                    });

            g.selectAll(".teamCircle").transition()
                    .duration(200)
                    .attr("opacity", function(d,j){
                        return j != i ? 0.6 : 1;
                    }); 

        });

        teamCircles.on("mousemove", function(d){

            d3.select(this)
                .classed("hover", true)
                .attr("stroke", "black")
                .attr("stroke-width", "1px");

            d3.select(this.parentNode)
                .select(".teamArc")
                .classed("hover", true)
                .attr("stroke", "black")
                .attr("stroke-width", "1px");        
        });

        teamCircles.on("mouseout", function(d){

            g.selectAll(".teamCircle")
                .transition()
                .duration(200)
                .attr("opacity", 1);

            g.selectAll(".teamArc")
                    .transition()
                    .duration(200)
                    .attr("opacity", 1);

            d3.select(this)
                .classed("hover", false)
                .attr("stroke", "black")
                .attr("stroke-width", "0px");

            d3.select(this.parentNode)
                .select(".teamArc")
                .classed("hover", false)
                .attr("stroke", "black")
                .attr("stroke-width", "0px");    

        });

        teamCircles.on("click", function(d){
            console.log("selected");
            g.selectAll(".teamCircle")
                    .attr("opacity", 0.6)
                    .attr("stroke-width", "0px");

            g.selectAll(".teamArc")
                    .attr("opacity", 0.6)
                    .attr("stroke-width", "0px");


            d3.select(this)
                .classed("clicked", true)
                .attr("opacity", 1)
                .attr("stroke", "green")
                .attr("stroke-width", "2px");

            d3.select(this.parentNode)
                .select(".teamArc")
                .classed("clicked", true)
                .attr("opacity", 1)
                .attr("stroke", "green")
                .attr("stroke-width", "2px");
        })

        teamArcs.on("mouseover", function(d,i){
                    //The following bit of code adapted from http://bl.ocks.org/WillTurman/4631136

            g.selectAll(".teamArc").transition()
                    .duration(200)
                    .attr("opacity", function(d,j){


                        return j != i ? 0.6 : 1;
                    });

            g.selectAll(".teamCircle").transition()
                    .duration(200)
                    .attr("opacity", function(d,j){
                        return j != i ? 0.6 : 1;
                    }); 

            // var clickedCircle = g.selectAll(".teamCircle")
            //                     .filter("active");

            // var clickedArc = g.selectAll(".teamArc")
            //                     .filter("active");

            // clickedArc.attr("fill", "green");

            // console.log(clickedCircle);
            // console.log(clickedArc);                        
        });

        teamArcs.on("mousemove", function(d){

            d3.select(this)
                .classed("hover", true)
                .attr("stroke", "black")
                .attr("stroke-width", "1px");

            d3.select(this.parentNode)
                .select(".teamCircle")
                .classed("hover", true)
                .attr("stroke", "black")
                .attr("stroke-width", "1px"); 
        });

        teamArcs.on("mouseout", function(d){
            g.selectAll(".teamArc")
                    .transition()
                    .duration(200)
                    .attr("opacity", "1");

            d3.select(this)
                .classed("hover", false)
                .attr("stroke", "black")
                .attr("stroke-width", "0px");

            d3.select(this.parentNode)
                .select(".teamCircle")
                .classed("hover", false)
                .attr("stroke", "black")
                .attr("stroke-width", "0px"); 

            g.selectAll(".teamCircle")
                .transition()
                .duration(200)
                .attr("opacity", 1);
        });
```

By default, I would like the first "player" (arc and circle) to be active. When the user hovers over another arc or circle, all of the arcs and circles except for the once that is active and the one that is being hovered should fade to opacity 0.6.

The problem I am having is that when I hover, all of the arcs and circles (including the active one) are fading out.

See the fiddle:[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/roushb/neppanj5/9/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter your selection and reject elements with "active" class.

```
teamArcs.on("mouseover", function(d, i) {
  //The following bit of code adapted from http://bl.ocks.org/WillTurman/4631136
  console.log("hello");
  g.selectAll(".teamArc")
    .filter(function() {
      return !this.classList.contains('active')
    })
    .transition()
    .duration(200)
    .attr("opacity", function(d, j) {
      return j != i - 1 ? 0.6 : 1;
    });

  g.selectAll(".teamCircle").transition()
    .filter(function() {
      return !this.classList.contains('active')
    })
    .duration(200)
    .attr("opacity", function(d, j) {
      return j != i - 1 ? 0.6 : 1;
    });
});
```

Working demo - https://jsfiddle.net/hmLu4zqb/

Comment: Thanks, but its not quite there. It seems that when you hover over one arc, the arc immediately next to it also activates. Perhaps that's somewhere else in my code. Really appreciate your help with the filtering though.

Comment: Oh, yes. I was no careful. You also should check index like:  `j != i - 1 ? 0.6 : 1`

Comment: Fixed it, the filtering messes up the index `i` so need to subtract one when  doing the opacity attribute testing. I modified it on your solution. Thanks again!